# Copy and Paste Key Shortcuts

Tags: copy, copy-and-paste

I have two Linux machines. On one machine, copy and paste is ctrl + c and ctrl + v.  On the other machine, it is ctrl + w and ctrl + y.  How can I change the general system setting to make them both use ctrl + v and ctrl + c?

Comment: There is no "general system setting" for copy and paste, especially on Linux where things are quite fragmented. Each application may respect a different set of configuration methods. Try asking a question about the specific application you want to configure.

Comment: Please provided OS & release details; and note for desktop/GUIs, they don't all use the same standards, and for some can use a variety of standards based on a number of factors (*most of which you control!*), but you've not provided any basic OS & release details, including GUI/desktop, which is what provides basic *software stack* details allowing us to understand what you're using.

Comment: It was Matlab, not a general system problem.  Thanks so much.